# How to disable flashing file names in rlogin

Tags: terminal, ls, colors

I have a strange problem with my rhel 6.4 system.
If I do a `rlogin` to any of my machines, all the files in the remore machine will be flashing and it is so annoying.
Can somebody please tell me how can I disable this?

Comment: A file is an invisible collection of bits on a disk. It could not possibly flash. Perhaps you mean some other flashy things, like *file names as shown by **ls** in the terminal*.

Comment: ya... the files which are listed after the ls command are flashing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several reason why the output of `ls` would blink. Here are some, roughly in a decreasing order of probability.

1. Your `$LS_COLORS` environment variable is set incorrectly.
2. Your `$LS_COLORS` environment variable is not set and your `/etc/DIR_COLORS` file is corrupt.
3. Your `$TERM` environment variable is set incorrectly.
4. All your files are in fact orphaned symbolic links.

A reasonably set `$LS_COLORS` should contain substrings like `or=01;05` and `mi=01;05` and there should be no more `05`s. Likewise, a reasonable `/etc/DIR_COLORS` should contain `05` in two places, near words ORPHAN and MISSING.

These settings make sure that `ls` shows just orphaned symbolic links, and missing files they point at, in blinking characters. `05` or `5` is the ANSI terminal escape code for blinking.